# Duplicate class javax.annotation found in modules jetified

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Hello for a work project i've implemented a new lib developped by someone in my workspace
I integrated his .jar file in my libs folder and tried to implement some code he asked me to but nothing seems to work and i still have a duplicated class issue
 `Duplicate class javax.annotation.Detainted found in modules jetified-IN-NistComponent-1.3.1 (IN-NistComponent-1.3.1.jar) and jetified-jsr305-3.0.2 (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2)`

What should i do to remove it ?

```
configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude(group = "org.jetbrains", module = "annotations")

    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(fileTree("libs"))
    /// Hilt

    implementation(androidlibs.hilt.android)
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.1")
    kapt(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)
    androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.android.testing)
    androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)
    testImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.android.testing)
    testImplementation(androidlibs.hilt.compiler)

    // Kotlinx Coroutines
    implementation(androidlibs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
    testImplementation(androidlibs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)

    /// AndroidX
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.constraintlayout)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.material)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.material.icons.extended)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.activity)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.camera2)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.view)
    implementation(androidlibs.androidx.camera.lifecycle)
    implementation(androidlibs.gson)

    //Lottie
    implementation(androidlibs.airbnb.android.lottie.compose)
    implementation(androidlibs.exoplayer)

    //Accompanist
    implementation(androidlibs.accompanist.permissions)

    // Timber
    implementation(androidlibs.timber)

    //implementation(androidlibs.coppernic.ibscanultimate)
    implementation(androidlibs.ibscanultimate)
    implementation(androidlibs.ibscancommon)


    implementation(androidlibs.cpcCore)
    implementation(androidlibs.cpcUtilsLib)


    implementation(androidlibs.retrofit)
    implementation(androidlibs.converter.gson)
    implementation(androidlibs.converter.simplexml)
    //Accompanist
    implementation(androidlibs.accompanist.permissions)

    // App Center
    "integrationImplementation"(androidlibs.appcenter.distribute)
    "integrationImplementation"(androidlibs.appcenter.crashes)

    testImplementation(androidlibs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.android.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.test.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.test.manifest)
    testImplementation(androidlibs.mockito.kotlin)


    debugImplementation(androidlibs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling)


    implementation("com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava")
    implementation(group = "xerces", name = "xercesImpl", version = "2.11.0")
```

the code in questions are the `configurations` block and the last 2 lines in dependencies.

for some context he provided me with the lines in groovy and i adapted them to work in kts for my gradle